# How to populate a week

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 3.2.14 app and I need to generate data from the database.
In this system I got 2 models (Project and Timereport).

Timereport is a polymorphic model (timereportable) and it got a table called total_time (in seconds).

Project has_many timereports.

What I need to achieve is to print out the total time for each projects split out on a week.
Like the illustration below:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| PROJECT | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun | Total |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| Drill   | 2.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 | 14.0  |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| Saw     | 1.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 | 9.0   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried it like this and it works but it feels very uneffective.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>Project</th>
      <th>Mon</th>
      <th>Tue</th>
      <th>Wed</th>
      <th>Thu</th>
      <th>Fri</th>
      <th>Sat</th>
      <th>Sun</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <% projects.each do |project| %>
        <%
          data = project.timereports.group("date(created_at)")
          data = data.created_between(Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week, Time.zone.now.end_of_week)
          data = data.order("date(created_at) ASC")
          data = data.select("date (created_at) as date, sum(total_time) as seconds")
          data.each do |post|
            day = Date.parse(post[:date]).strftime("%A")
            if (weekday == "Monday")
                  @days[:mon] += seconds
                elsif (weekday == "Tuesday")
                  @days[:tue] += seconds
                elsif (weekday == "Wednesday")
                  @days[:wed] += seconds
                elsif (weekday == "Thursday")
                  @days[:thu] += seconds
                elsif (weekday == "Friday")
                  @days[:fri]+= seconds
                elsif (weekday == "Saturday")
                  @days[:sat] += seconds
                elsif (weekday == "Sunday")
                  @days[:sun] += seconds
                end
          end
        %>
        <tr>
              <td><%= link_to project.title.capitalize, admin_projects_path(project) %></td>
              <td><%= split_time_simple @days[:mon] %></td>
              <td><%= split_time_simple @days[:tue] %></td>
              <td><%= split_time_simple @days[:wed] %></td>
              <td><%= split_time_simple @days[:thu] %></td>
              <td><%= split_time_simple @days[:fri] %></td>
              <td><%= split_time_simple @days[:sat] %></td>
              <td><%= split_time_simple @days[:sun] %></td>
              <td><%= split_time_simple @days[:mon] + @days[:tue] + @days[:wed] + @days[:thu] + @days[:fri] + @days[:sat] + @days[:sun] %></td>
            </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**Update**

The above code "works" but I suspect that it is deeply inefficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not use a [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html)?

Comment: Ok, done. I am using hash instead of instance variables now. Good catch! What do you think can be improved?

Comment: Why instead of additional query per project to sum the times you wrote some monster-code to sum in IN A VIEW?

Comment: Yeah I know it´s an anti pattern but I am not sure how to do it in the controller in a good way.

Comment: Or even now, you just do `data.inject(0) { |sum, n| sum + n[:seconds] }` which gives you sum for project for selected data?

Comment: And for the displaying, you select 7 rows of result, which are ordered by date so you know they go from mon to sun, so why the hell you reassign them to instance vars?

Comment: I changed to a hash instead of using instance variables now but the reason I am doing this anyway is to put the correct time into the correct day. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not optimal solution (I use `weekly_report` and not sure if Rails will cache it, probably not) but way better that original.

project.rb:

```
def weekly_report
  self.timereports.group("date(created_at)") \
                  .created_between(Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week, Time.zone.now.end_of_week) \
                  .order("date(created_at) ASC") \
                  .select("date (created_at) as date, sum(total_time) as seconds")
end
```

controller:

```
@projects = Project.all # or whatever else the criteria is
```

view:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <% projects.each do |project| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= link_to project.title.capitalize, admin_projects_path(project) %></td>
          <%= project.weekly_report.each do |day|
            <td><%= split_time_simple day[:seconds] %></td>
          <% end %>
          <td><%= split_time_simple project.weekly_report.inject(0) { |sum, n| sum + n[:seconds] } %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Cool, it almost works perfectly! I need however to print out <td> with a 0 in them when there is no time for that day. Right now I have no way of knowing which day the time belongs to and which days that are lacking a time.

Comment: It worked but there were no empty <td>s which caused the table to look broken. Love you idea so I combined it with some of mine. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, ok, you're right. Since you don't care about the date this could be improved nicely, what DB do you use?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL at Heroku. How can it be improved?

Comment: Would be cool if I only needed one query for all the timereports and one for all the projects. Is this possible?

Comment: I didn't try it but this should select just a month `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM projects.created_at)`

Comment: Yeah, it is but that would be a little more tricky and I'm not sure if handling it in Ruby will not take just as much time. You could `Timereport.(...).select("project_id, date (created_at) as date, sum(total_time) as seconds")`, again you have to test it, I'm not sure if it will work